# how to import Eclipse project to Android Studio without Eclipse

Tags: android, import, android-studio

I get Android project from Eclipse, and I can import it to my Android Studio. I read all instructions about it... first step is export this project from eclipse. But I dont have eclipse and I cant install it.
Can I import this project without Eclipse?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation at the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) says:

> Note: It's possible to import an existing Android project to Android
>   Studio even if you don't generate a Gradle build file from
>   Eclipse—Android Studio will successfully build and run projects using
>   an existing Ant build file. However, in order to take advantage of
>   build variants and other advanced features in the future, we strongly
>   suggest that you generate a Gradle build file using the ADT plugin or
>   write your own Gradle build file for use with Android Studio. For more
>   information about the Gradle build system, see the Gradle Plugin User
>   Guide.

Comment: If your project isn't complicated, then creating a build.gradle file for it shouldn't be too hard. You can try doing it by hand, or you could create a new project in Android studio and crib its build file to get you started. We're planning on direct import of Eclipse projects into Android Gradle projects; that's being tracked in bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61878 but we won't start on it for a while yet.